# How to display all results of one PHP variable together from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I am having an unexpected ton of difficulty trying to return all the currencies that a store accepts from the currency(banking) table.

**The results I want should be:**

Store name: Test
Store type: Grocery Store
Currency accepted: Bitcoin, Euros, Dollars

**The results I get (when I remove GROUPBY Store) are:**
Store name: Test
Store type: Grocery Store
Currency accepted: Bitcoin

Store name: Test
Store type: Grocery Store
Currency accepted: Euros

Store name: Test
Store type: Grocery Store
Currency accepted: Dollars

**When I remove groupby store, then I only get the first result above (just the bitcoin result for currency)**

There are 3 rows for the store id for currency, but it is only returning the first row's value (Bitcoin) since I am using GROUPBY and only one one result for the Test Store (But all 3 currencies for that store). I can't seem to get it to pull all 3 matching rows for the store id in that table into my results so that I get the 3 currencies returned.

I know the query is good from other tests, but I just don't know how to adjust the code below so that all currencies are returned and listed for the "Currency Accepted" table row on the page.

Here is the relevant code:

```
$query = "(
SELECT * FROM store
LEFT JOIN store_banking SB ON store.id=SB.store_id
LEFT JOIN banking B ON  SB.banking_id = B.id

LEFT JOIN store_gaming SG ON store.id=SG.store_id
LEFT JOIN gaming G ON  SG.gaming_id = G.id
WHERE 
('$type' IS NULL OR '$type' = '' OR G.type = '$type')
And
('$currency' IS NULL OR '$currency' = '' OR B.currency= '$currency')
GROUP BY store.name
Order by store.name
)";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='5'>
<tr>
<th>Store Name</th>
<th>Type</th>
<th>Currency Accepted:</th> //need this to show all 3 matches; only showing 1
</tr>";

/* fetch associative array */
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['currency'] . "</td>"; //only returns first results row :(
echo "</tr>";
}

/* free result set */
mysqli_free_result($result);

echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Couple of notes from a quick glance: You only seem to select from `store`; What happens if you remove the `WHERE` clauses?; What happens when you dump `$result` - with and without the `WHERE` clauses?

Comment: @James nothing helpful when I print_r or var_dump. Just "( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 30 [lengths] => Array ( [0] =>" and so on. I know all the results are returning just fine. They display in each placeholder on the page as I want. But only fort the first result set. If I remove the groupby clause, then I get 3 sets of results (one for each currency). But again, that's the issue. Want 3 currencies listed together for the given store.

Comment: It just occured to me that as long as I have the "Groupby Store" clause, I will only get the one currency result. SO I think I need to groupby to be applied to all fields EXCEPT the currency table/currency field somehow?

Comment: There needs to be something in the <?php echo $row['currency']; ?> code that tells it echo all 3 results from the search. It gets all 3 currently but how group together right where it says "currency accepted"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) might do the trick for you.

And when you select with `GROUP_CONCAT` it's often best to set an alias on the select to easier reference it later.

For example:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(currency) as currency
```

Comment: I like the idea, but not sure you can use Group_CONCAT with join queries. I tried adding it like "SELECT name,
           GROUP_CONCAT(currency) 
     FROM Stores" and I get error "Undefined index".

Comment: also, not sure I do select all (*) and add group_concat for just one field, at least not in join queries.

Comment: Try `SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(currency) as currency FROM Stores`

Comment: Sweet! That did it. I also had to add distinct, like: GROUP_CONCAT(distinct currency)